# Две мои ноги или две моих ноги?

Tags: склонение

Как будет правильно?

У него рука как две мои ноги.
У него рука как две моих ноги.

Склоняюсь к первому варианту, но часто встречается и второй.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить вопросы к согласуемым словам. Это поможет написать правильно.

> У него рука как две *(чьи?)* мои ноги.

В каком случае было бы правильно "моих"? Например, в таком:

> У него рука толще двух *(чьих?)* моих ног.

(в последнем примере было бы красивее сказать "рука толще моих двух ног", но я оставил порядок слов для наглядности)

Comment: *У него рука как две (чьи?) мои ноги.* - А почему не "чьих?".

Comment: Вариант "чьих" ("Вы чьих будете?") - устаревший, восходит к эпохе крепостного права. Сейчас так говорят только в том случае, если сознательно хотят сделать стилизацию под старину.

Comment: То есть Розенталь пропагандирует нормы времен крепостного права? )))

Comment: В серьезных справочниках обычно упоминаются все варианты, в том числе и вышедшие из обихода - это вполне нормально. Но вот пропаганды там точно нет :)

Comment: Пока у Розенталя нет ничего устаревшего (про "*Вы чьих будете?*" и подобное он ничего не говорил).

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, что я ничего не писал конкретно про Розенталя, я писал про подход в целом. Про Розенталя и пропаганду писал уважаемый behemothus. Я лишь хочу еще раз повторить: "чьих" в данном случае - устаревшая форма. Современные носители русского языка так не говорят, и эта форма осталась только в некоторых академических справочниках и в стилизациях "под старину".

Comment: В данном случае — да. Здесь сама конструкция  (даже "*Вы чьи будете?*") устарела в плане стилистики. Но behemothus говорил не об этом примере, а о "*У него рука как две моих ноги*", а здесь ничего устаревшего не наблюдается. *я писал про подход в целом* — в справочниках речь о действующих на момент выхода правилах, об устаревших (как бы неправильных) не говорится, так как оно ни к чему. А если речь всё же о том, что правила в справочниках устаревают (что очевидно), так как язык развивается и меняется, то это никак не подход.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky *"чьих" в данном случае* - Не в данном, а в том, что лично вы предложили. Да и то, устаревшей надо признать не столько форму, сколько ситуацию. **Данная** же (автором) форма вполне допускает вопрос "чьих", ничего устаревшего в ней нету. У Розенталя: http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliv-soglasovanie-opredeleniy-i-prilozheniy/ss-193-opredelenie-pri-sushchestvitelnom-zavisyashchem-ot-chislitelnyh-dva-tri-chetyre

Comment: 3. Притяжательные прилагательные на — ин и — ов обычно ставятся в родительном падеже множественного числа независимо от грамматического рода имени существительного: два бабушкиных сарафана, три сестриных подруги, два чертовых ущелья.
Притяжательные прилагательные на — ий, — ья, -ье, а также порядковое числительное третий согласуются в зависимости от рода определяемого существительного: два лисьих хвоста, два вороньих гнезда, две медвежьи берлоги; два третьих приза — две третьи премии.

Comment: Понятно, что в этих случая вопрос "чьих?" - и только он. Но не может же грамматическая форма требуемого вопроса зависеть от наперед заданной формы ответа? Мы же наоборот посиупаем (и вы так советуете) - по форме вопроса определяем ответ.

Comment: @behemothus, Вы привели примеры притяжательных прилагательных. Какое отношение они имеют к форме местоимения "мои"?

Comment: @Ivan Olshansky *Вы привели примеры притяжательных прилагательных.* - Я не приводил примеры притяжательных прилагательных. Я привел примеры из Розенталя, которые показывают некорректносить вашего утверждения о том, что конструкция "чьих" устаревшая.

Comment: @behemothus, возможно я неправильно понял посыл Ваших постов, в которых все примеры были с притяжательными прилагательными, извините.

Comment: Но тогда втстречный вопрос.  А какое огтношените имеет вообще форма "чьих будете" к согласованию формы определения в конструкции с числительным "два (три четыре)"

Comment: @behemothus, никакого отношения не имеет. Именно поэтому, когда мы спрашиваем про местоимение, используется вопрос "чьи", а не "чьих": две (чьи) ноги? Две мои ноги. Если бы мы спрашивали про прилагательное, мы могли бы поставить вопрос "каких?": две (каких) ноги? Две бабушкиных ноги. Но вопрос "чьих" мы бы здесь не применяли в любом случае.

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:
Если формы именительного падежа множественного числа существительных женского рода отличаются по ударению от формы родительного падежа единственного числа (ср.: *го́ры — горы́, слёзы — слезы́*), то определение в рассматриваемой конструкции обычно ставится в родительном падеже множественного числа: *две высоких горы, две крупных слезы.*  Например: *Три серых струны натянулись в воздухе* (Горький); *Две сильных мужских руки подхватили ее* (А. Коптяева).
http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliv-soglasovanie-opredeleniy-i-prilozheniy/ss-193-opredelenie-pri-sushchestvitelnom-zavisyashchem-ot-chislitelnyh-dva-tri-chetyre

Здесь тоже формы отличаются по ударению.

Answer (score 0):

Очень интересный вопрос. На мой взгляд корректно и так и так. По сути все сводится к корректности следующих предложений:

```
Вы чьих будете?
Вы чьи будете?
```

При этом ответ будет один и тот же:

```
Мы своих родителей будем.
```

Это доказывает корректность первого вопроса (второй, очевидно, корректен).
При этом более контекстуально-конкретный вопрос как раз первый. Следовательно он более грамматически четкий в соответствующем контексте.

Можно еще сослаться на такое:

```
Рука как две каких ноги? - Рука как две моих ноги.
Рука как две какие ноги? - Рука как две мои ноги.
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131127/discussion-on-answer-by-user190920-------).